# /sys/fs/selinux/policy doesn't get loaded

Tags: policy, selinux

I am working in an ecosystem wherein a main server running RHEL8.4 boots up first, and then for any accessory single CPU machine that boots up subsequently, a copy of the loaded OS is transferred at boot time to the machine by means of IPXE.

On the server, the directory `/etc/selinux` is soft-linked to a persistent path on /data, so that the policy remains unchanged between successive boot cycles. Additionally, on the server the policy under `/sys/fs/selinux` gets loaded from the policy under `/etc/selinux` (this is my understanding; please correct me if it is misplaced). Consequently, the policy file under `/sys/fs/selinux` is not empty.

On the single cpu machines, the soft link from `/etc/selinux` to `/data` is present, but the policy file under `/sys/fs/selinux` is empty. I am assuming that this is due to the fact that the policy file doesn't get loaded from the policy under `/etc/selinux`.

Any thoughts on why the policy file doesn't get loaded in one case, for the same version of the OS, on different instances?

TIA

Comment: fyi this should be posted to [unix.se]. Stack Overflow is for programming Q&A.

Comment: ... or possibly to [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/)